# TinyMCE Removes site base url

Tags: tinymce

im using TinyMCE Wysiwyg editor, and when i enter a link, or an image from the same website, it removes the base url

for example, if i enter: http://www.domain.com/somelink.php - i'll get - somelink.php

any ideas how to solve it?

thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get TinyMCE to use full image url instead of relative one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796942/get-tinymce-to-use-full-image-url-instead-of-relative-one)

Comment: @BenoitGarret: Does July come after September?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Add this few lines in your tinyMCE.init function :

```
convert_urls:true,
relative_urls:false,
remove_script_host:false,
```

Comment: it seems `convert_urls: false` is enough - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40168167/1788684

Answer (score 3):

(Old thread I know but in case anyone else is googling this:)

I had to set convert_urls to false as well.

I am using TinyMCE within Umbraco, so I needed to make the changes in /config/tinyMceConfig.config and then restart the website.

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to solve.

Instead of Epharion said, simply put this line in your tinyMCE.init function:

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        document_base_url : "http://www.site.com/path1/"
});
```