# Get TinyMCE to use full image url instead of relative one

Tags: url, tinymce

I use TinyMCE as editor on a website. Problem is, when I insert images from the same site, TinyMCE will use relative url to the image instead of the fixed url I entered when including the image.

The resulting html is used elsewhere, for example in emails. Problem is, relative urls will not show up properly anywhere but in the original location.

How do I get TinyMCE to use full absolute urls instead of shortened relative ones?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Make sure in the javascript initialization you are using, that you have these lines in it:

```
relative_urls : false,
remove_script_host : false,
convert_urls : true,
```

Read more: [TinyMCE - URL handling options](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/url-handling)

Comment: I don't understand what convert_urls does, but the rest works as expected.

Comment: @Sam : check this https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/url-handling/#convert_urls

Comment: For me `convert_urls` was not needed (I'm using the [TinyMCE Django plugin](http://django-tinymce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)), since the default value is already 'true'.

Answer (score 12):

As it was previously pointed out, this the correct way:

```
relative_urls : false,
remove_script_host : false,
convert_urls : true,
```

HOWEVER, there is one thing to mention that will make you wonder why it's not working even though you have specified the proper text above.  Ensure the false and true do NOT have quotes around them.

The following is incorrect:

```
relative_urls : "false",
```

Answer (score 5):

You can only add convert_urls : false

Here's the documentation
http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:convert_urls

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the config parameter relative_urls to false and see if that helps:

http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/relative_urls