# absolute URL with TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

Everytime i add an image to tinyMCE it converts the image URL to something stupid (removes the hostname and adds ../ or whatever it needs) , so i won't be able to use the image created by tinymce in any other level of the site !

can this be fixed somehow ? `relative_urls: "false",` not working

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Before initializing tinymce i set the following variable

```
var system_url = "http://myserver.com/workspace/codebase/html/";
```

so that i am able to use `system_url` later for adressing images and other files like this

```
content_css: system_url+'js/tiny_mce/css/green.css',
```

Comment: seems there's a bug in tinymce ... it's not working . but the function is correct . thanks

Answer (score 12):

Use this in your javascript initialization:

```
relative_urls : false,
remove_script_host : false,
convert_urls : true,
```

[Get TinyMCE to use full image url instead of relative one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796942/get-tinymce-to-use-full-image-url-instead-of-relative-one)