# rich:editor disable convert_urls relative_urls on inserting image

Tags: jsf, tinymce, richfaces, seam

I use rich editor(Seam, jsf) and here is my code:

```
<rich:editor value="#{bean.variableName}" height="280" width="400" theme="advanced" id="editor">
   <f:param name="theme_advanced_buttons1" value="save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect"/>
   <f:param name="theme_advanced_buttons2" value="cut,pasteword,copy,paste,pastetext,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor,hr,removeformat,visualaid,"/>
   <f:param name="theme_advanced_toolbar_location" value="top"/>
   <f:param name="theme_advanced_toolbar_align" value="left"/>
   <f:param name="theme_advanced_statusbar_location" value="bottom"/>
   <f:param name="theme_advanced_resizing" value="true"/>
   <f:param name="language" value="#{locale.language}"/>
```

when I insert image from external url there is no problem,
but when I insert image from the same the host where the application is, the image url is converted(shortens)

from

```
<img src="https://myhost/path/my_image.png" />
```

to

```
<img src="../../my_image.png" />
```

I tried to find it out with options of rich:editor(http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/editor.jsf?tab=info&cid=979762)
but it seems like there is no an appropriate option, also I found issue in stackoverflow [Disable TinyMCE absolute to relative URL Conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196205/disable-tinymce-url-conversions), but there is in js, unlike in my case, I tried to find where rich:editor takes the tinymce from, to edit there js file(if like so exists), but I couldn't find it. Help me please with these url conversion problem, thanks!

Comment: I've solved the problem, just passed as parameter.  <rich:editor value="#{online.page.content}" height="280" width="400" theme="advanced" id="editor">
  .....
  <f:param name="convert_urls" value="false"/>
  <f:param name="relative_urls" value="false"/>
</rich:editor>